# Execute the registry section after the custom wizard?

Tags: registry, inno-setup

My question is little weird I guess, Is it possible to execute the registry section after the custom wizard? which appears right after the Installing page. Please let me know whether it is possible or not.

My planned execution flow is : -->Installing page-->My Custom Wizard page-->Finish Page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible with standard `[Registry]` section because it is always processed during actual installation process and this can't be changed:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installorder

But you can achieve what you need if you will drop standard `[Registry]` section and do the same by custom script on your custom Wizard page.